# Build a tree from a flat array in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I've looked around the internet and haven't quite found what I'm looking for. I have a flat array with each element containing an 'id' and a 'parent_id'. Each element will only have ONE parent, but may have multiple children. If the parent_id = 0, it is considered a root level item. I'm trying to get my flat array into a tree. The samples I have found only working for core php. Because in codeigniter recursive is not qorking

```
function buildTree(array &$elements, $parentId = 0) {
    $branch = array();

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[$element['id']] = $element;
            unset($elements[$element['id']]);
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}
```

My Flat array is

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent_id] => 0
            [permission_category] => Listing

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [parent_id] => 1
            [permission_category] => Tour
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [parent_id] => 1
            [permission_category] => Activity
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [parent_id] => 0
            [permission_category] => Bookings
            [parent_permission_category] => 
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [parent_id] => 12
            [permission_category] => Activity Bookings
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [parent_id] => 12
            [permission_category] => Tour Bookings
        )

);
```

It is only showing one parent children

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent_id] => 0
            [permission_category] => Listing
            [children] => Array
                (

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [permission_category] => Tour
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [permission_category] => Activity
                        )
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: The buildTree() method seems to work fine for me. What exactly is the problem you are having with it?

Comment: I would suggest removing the unset() line from the method. That seems to be causing some problems.

Comment: unable to recurse the function in codigniter helper